# how to deploy coprocessor to CDH4 HBase cluster

Tags: hbase, cloudera

What is the recommended way to deploy a region coprocessor jar to an HBase cluster running CDH 4 with Cloudera Manager?  Specifically, is there a recommended way to distribute the jar and add it to each regionserver's classpath?  Ideally I would add it to the /lib directory in HDFS, but this raises two questions:

1. Is it possible to add an HDFS uri to the java class path, such as `hdfs:///lib`?
2. How is the HBase classpath changed in Cloudera manager?  I cannot find a configuration setting corresponding to adding `export HBASE_CLASSPATH=hdfs:///lib` to hbase-env.sh

Answer (score 1):

We can put coprocessor jars into hdfs path, but you should not define it in HBASE_CLASSPATH, only you can do is: Create/Alter table , put the hdfs into the method:

htd.addCoprocessor(className, jarFilePath, priority, kvs);